# It is possible to generate daily checklist from org todo list?

Tags: org-mode, todo

Say I have a file called schedule.org, which looks like

```
* Coursework
** Corporate Finance Theory 
*** TODO Lecture
    SCHEDULED: <2017-09-28 Thu 9:00-12:15 +1w>
*** NEXT Review Bolton & Freixas (2000)
    SCHEDULED: <2017-09-23 Sat>
```

Is it possible to general another org file which contains a daily checklist

```
* 2016
** 2016-09
*** 2016-09-23
-[] Review Bolton & Freixas (2000)
*** 2016-09-28
-[] Lecture
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've been following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQS06Qjnkcc&list=PLVtKhBrRV_ZkPnBtt_TD1Cs9PJlU0IIdE and he also mentions a daily checklist like this, but he doesn't seem to be automating this.

I've been looking at https://github.com/bastibe/org-journal and https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiaryMode. But both don't seem to provide something like this.

(I know this isn't an answer, but I considered it too much to be posted in a comment)

Answer (score 0):

In [this org-mode checklists video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvgfmED8RD4)  the author creates daily checklist manually by viewing at his agenda files.

You can create a capture template this way:

```
("d" "Daily" checkitem (file+olp+datetree "~/Dropbox/org/journal.org") " [ ] %a %?\n\n" :prepend t :kill-buffer t)
```

So that you can visit each task, call capture template to record task with a link back to the TODO entry.